# Linux application project for zynq7000 in the Xilinx SDK

Tags: linux, sdk, arm, elf, xilinx

I'm trying to create a Linux application to run on my Zynq7020. However I don't understand how the Xilinx SDK generate the executable file.

When I create a hello world, for instance, it creates one .elf file and under the debug it creates one object (.o) and one dependency (.d). I want to run it under the Linux that is running on my board, how do I do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run it under the Linux that is running on my board, how do I do it?

Most likely, you just need to copy/download the `.elf` file to your target board and run it.

If that doesn't work, try editing your question to supply more info. In particular, what commands "create a hello world" actually executes?

Comment: I already tried to run on my board, however when I try to do it, it just says: "Illegal instruction". My hello world is just a hello world (include <stdio.h> int main(){printf("a");return 0;}.
If I write it and compile it using the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi, which is the one present on my linux, it compile and runs. I don't know why the SDK output doesn't work. Please let me know if you need further details or if I'm doing something wrong.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When creating the project in the Xilinx SDK, select that it runs on linux rather than standalone. See [this](https://www.xilinx.com/video/hardware/how-to-create-linux-applications.html) official tutorial for an in-depth explanation.